# Are stand-offs unnecessary when the case is made of plastic?

Tags: cases, plastic

If a case is plastic, would there be any real benefit to using stand-offs to ensure the circuit board is not in contact with the side of the plastic case? Even when the plastic is non-conductive?

(The context here is the casual, do-it-yourself casing of small home projects.)

Comment: Only thing I can think of is airflow around parts that get hot, and standoffs allow the board to be secured and not move inside the case.

Comment: Standoffs also keep the board from getting flexed, if you have parts on both sides, or leds sticking out from through-hole parts the board might bend if you are mounting from holes in the corners

Comment: When feeling lazy, I've been known to secure one-off projects assembled on protoboard to plastic cases with double-sided foam tape. Cheap, easy, fast, and good enough.

Comment: I've made quick standoffs by using running extra nuts down on the screw under the board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Most types of plastic have the possibility of causing ESD problems.